# How to prove that $\hat{A}\phi = \phi^2$ is a linear operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

In my textbook it is written that an operator $\hat{A}$ is linear if it satisfies the condition:

$$ \hat{A}(c\phi)= c\hat{A}\phi $$

Then they ask us to prove whether $\hat{A}\psi=\phi^2$ is a linear operator; their solution is to show that on the left hand side we get:

$$ \hat{A}(c\phi)= c^2\phi^2 $$

and on the right hand side:

$$ c\hat{A}\phi=c\phi^2 $$

LHS being different from RHS, $\hat{A}$ is not a linear operator.

It makes sense for the last line, but I don't understand how they obtained the results in both sides applying the initial condition, and how they get rid of  $\psi$ ?

Comment: I've edited your question to use MathJax for the equations. You might want to check that I haven't misunderstood anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of $\phi$"? What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking, the condition for linearity is that,

$$\hat A (f+g) = \hat A f + \hat A g$$

as well as,

$$\hat A (cf) = c\hat A f$$

where $c$ is a constant. The behaviour of your operator is defined such that $\hat A f = f^2$ which is not  a linear operator. We can see this using the first condition, other than the one you showed, since

$$\hat A (f+g) = (f+g)^2 = f^2 + g^2 + 2fg$$

whereas, $\hat A f + \hat A g = f^2 + g^2$ and since they differ by $2fg$, the operation cannot be linear.